# How to change position add input fields

Tags: jquery

I have problem with set the position of the new input text.

Now everyone is located below the frame,

[image]

But I would like to put it above the Dodaj znajomego"'s buton.

Here is the jsfiddle demo: jsfiddle.net/L77px/2

Comment: link to jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/L77px/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use below JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
     var inp = $('.odstep25');
     $('<div class="odstep15"> </div> <div class="form_rightPart"> <input type="text" placeholder="Imie znajomego" name="name" maxlength="30"> </div> <div class="odstep5"> </div> <div class="form_rightPart"> <input type="text" name="znajomyemail" maxlength="30" placeholder="Wpisz adres e-mail"> </div>').appendTo(inp);
  });
});
```

This will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/L77px/3/)**

You have to append the new html to `<div class="form_rightPart">`

```
var inp = $('.form_rightPart');
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var inp = $('.form_rightPart');
        $('<div class="odstep15"> </div> <div class="form_rightPart"> <input type="text" placeholder="Imie znajomego" name="name" maxlength="30"> </div> <div class="odstep5"> </div> <div class="form_rightPart"> <input type="text" name="znajomyemail" maxlength="30" placeholder="Wpisz adres e-mail"> </div>').appendTo(inp);
    });
});
```